# How to install google chrome browser on a i386 (32 bit) ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, 32-bit

I tried to install using following command for 32-bit system.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

But I got an error:

```
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.199.174, 2404:6800:4009:807::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.199.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-06-30 20:05:59 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me it seems as the download was deleted because this browser is not supported any more from Google. Why didn't you try to install chromium?

But even you need the download:
https://archive.org/download/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb

Comment: Note that the version on Archive.org is outdated - I'd recommend switching to another browser (such as Chromium, which is the open-source version of chrome), or upgrading to a 64-bit system.